# "Elixir + phoenix" filtering websocket messages

Tags: websocket, elixir, phoenix-framework

I try to preprocess websocket incoming messages. In `lobby_channel.ex` file I have:

```
defmodule Chatroom.LobbyChannel do
  use Phoenix.Channel

  def join("room:lobby", _payload, socket) do
    {:ok, socket}
  end
  def join("room:" <> _private_room_id, _params, _socket) do
    {:error, %{reason: "unauthorized"}}
  end

  def handle_in("new_move", payload, socket) do
    changeset = Chatroom.Move.changeset(%Chatroom.Move{}, payload)

    if changeset.valid? do
      broadcast! socket, "new_move", payload
      {:noreply, socket}
    else
      IO.puts "-----" <> changeset.errors[:message]
      push socket, "error", %{msg: "Invalid move"}
      {:noreply, socket}
    end
  end

  #intercept ["new_move"]
  #def handle_out("new_move", payload, socket) do
  #  IO.puts payload["name"] <> "=======" <> payload["message"]
  #  push socket, "new_move", payload
  #  {:noreply, socket}
  #end
end
```

Model file contains validation functions:

```
...
def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
  struct
  |> cast(params, [:name, :message])
  |> validate_required([:name, :message])
  |> validate_length(:name, min: 1)
  |> validate_length(:message, is: 2)
  |> is_move_allowed(params)
end

defp is_move_allowed(changeset, params) do
  IO.puts "--zz---" <> params["message"]

  if params["message"] == "00" do
    IO.puts "--yy---" <> params["message"]
    add_error(changeset, params["message"], "'message' cannot be '00'")
  else
    IO.puts "--xx---" <> params["message"]
    []
  end
end
...
```

..the last one is my custom validation function and I can't make it working without errors. The output I get:

```
--zz---00
--yy---00
[error] GenServer #PID<0.445.0> terminating
** (ArgumentError) argument error
    :erlang.byte_size(nil)
    (chatroom) web/channels/lobby_channel.ex:18: Chatroom.LobbyChannel.handle_in/3
    (phoenix) lib/phoenix/channel/server.ex:226: anonymous fn/4 in Phoenix.Channel.Server.handle_info/2
    (stdlib) gen_server.erl:601: :gen_server.try_dispatch/4
    (stdlib) gen_server.erl:667: :gen_server.handle_msg/5
    (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:247: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
Last message: %Phoenix.Socket.Message{event: "new_move", payload: %{"message" => "00", "name" => "a"}, ref: "2", to
pic: "room:lobby"}
State: %Phoenix.Socket{assigns: %{}, channel: Chatroom.LobbyChannel, channel_pid: #PID<0.445.0>, endpoint: Chatroom
.Endpoint, handler: Chatroom.UserSocket, id: nil, joined: true, pubsub_server: Chatroom.PubSub, ref: nil, serialize
r: Phoenix.Transports.WebSocketSerializer, topic: "room:lobby", transport: Phoenix.Transports.WebSocket, transport_
name: :websocket, transport_pid: #PID<0.439.0>}
```

As I understand, things are moving to the right way logically, message contains correct data, but how can I fix the error? What am I missing?

Comment: Try changing `[]` in else to `changeset`.

Comment: @Dogbert, the same error. For "00" message and all others

Comment: Can you post the complete contents of `web/channels/lobby_channel.ex`?

Comment: Ah, try `add_error(changeset, :message, "'message' cannot be '00'")`.

Comment: @Dogbert, thanks, third mistake is that `IO.puts "-----" <> changeset.errors[:message]` should be replaced with **inspect**: `IO.inspect changeset.errors`. You can summarize these 3 fixes in a main answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three errors in the code:

1. `is_move_allowed` must always return a Changeset. You're returning `[]` in else.
2. `add_error`'s second argument should be an atom
3. `changeset.errors[:message]` is a tuple, so you cannot use `<>` to concatenate it with a String. `IO.inspect` is a better alternative as it'll print any value.

So, change:

```
if params["message"] == "00" do
  IO.puts "--yy---" <> params["message"]
  add_error(changeset, params["message"], "'message' cannot be '00'")
else
  IO.puts "--xx---" <> params["message"]
  []
end
```

to:

```
if params["message"] == "00" do
  IO.puts "--yy---" <> params["message"]
  add_error(changeset, :message, "'message' cannot be '00'")
else
  IO.puts "--xx---" <> params["message"]
  changeset
end
```

and change:

```
IO.puts "-----" <> changeset.errors[:message]
```

to:

```
IO.inspect changeset.errors[:message]
# or IO.inspect changeset.errors
```